# Is there a word for "teacher's withholding knowledge"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I know there's a sinhalese word (ගුරු මුෂ්ටි) but can't remember the English word for that?

Comment: Need more context.  Also, sample sentence with blank for the word you are seeking.   What is the motivation of the teacher in withholding knowledge?  Does it make sense considering the level of instruction?

Comment: Pleading the Fifth.

Comment: @ab2 Sometimes teachers don't want to teach all the things they know specially when it comes to martial arts or even music. This happened in ancient times mostly cause they were probably afraid the student/s will overtake them and they will lose their jobs. Legend says lots of knowledge had been lost due to this practise by ancient teachers when it comes to medicine, martial arts and music.

Comment: Can you give more context? Is this teacher being mean, withholding info on purpose to make you study your books? Or are they witholding the info to prevent important info from getting out of the secret club? Google translate says 'guru musti' = 'teachers punch', which isn't immediately evocative of witholding knowledge but of corporal punishment

Comment: Many U.S. law schools use a form of teaching that they view (erroneously, in my opinion) as an offshoot of the Socratic method. Using it primarily involves challenging whatever answer a student gives with instances that render the student's answer absurd; the point, perhaps, is to persuade students that there are no right answers—there are only arguments. The popular idiomatic term for this approach is "[hiding the ball](https://lawweb.colorado.edu/profiles/pubpdfs/schlag/SchlagNYU.pdf)."

Answer (score 1):

**Obscurantism** — [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscurantism)

> *noun* 1. opposition to the spread of knowledge :  a policy of withholding knowledge from the general public

"Obscurantism" works here. It's a deliberate practice and it's meant to hold others back by withholding knowledge.

Comment: By not mentioning the Simplex method to GCSE students learning linear programming, I consider I was doing most of them a favour. Make that all of them.